# Как в QLineEdit передать нажатую клавишу?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, keypressevent

Как в '`line`' записать нажатую клавишу?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import sqlite3
import keyboard


def key():
    a = keyboard.read_key()

    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotkey (key1 TEXT)''')
        query = """ UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = ? """
        cursor.execute(query, (a,))
        db.commit()
    return a

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)

        letters_regex = QtCore.QRegExp("[a-z][A-Z]+")
        hotkeys_validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(letters_regex)

        self.line.setMaxLength(1)
        self.line.setValidator(hotkeys_validator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: через сигналы \ слоты

Comment: не понятна реализация

Comment: создаешь сигнал и слот, на модуль keyboard вешаешь обработчик в котором делаешь эмит сигнала. в слот пиши обработку интерфейса пользователя. соединяешь сигнал со слотом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю зачем вы в вопросе: 'Как в QLineEdit записать нажатую клавишу?'
вы показываете какие-то действия с *`sqlite3`*.

*Qt* может получить доступ к событиям клавиатуры,
только если любое из его окон верхнего уровня имеет фокус клавиатуры.
Если окно свернуто или другое окно сфокусировано, вы не будете получать события клавиатуры.

Вы ничего не написали почему и для чего вы используете модуль **`keyboard`**,
но раз вы его используете, значит вы хотите получить доступ к клавиатуре
даже если ваше окно свернуто или ваше окно не имеет фокуса.

Если это так, то как вариант, решение вопроса может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import keyboard
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
  

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.lineEdit_hotkey1 = QLineEdit()
#-        self.lineEdit_hotkey1.textChanged.connect(self.funny)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lineEdit_hotkey1)

        self.qwindowIsActive = True
        self.hook = None
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_qwindow)

    def on_qwindow(self):       
        self.qwindow = self.windowHandle()
        self.qwindow.activeChanged.connect(self.handle_activeChanged)

    def handle_activeChanged(self):
        print("окно активное (isActive)? {}".format(self.qwindow.isActive()))           
        if self.qwindow.isActive():
            self.qwindowIsActive = True
        else:
            self.qwindowIsActive = False
        self.setGrabbing()    
        
    def setGrabbing(self): 
        if not self.qwindowIsActive:                                  # если окно не активное 
            self.hook = keyboard.hook(self.keyboardEventReceived)            
        else:
            if self.hook:
                keyboard.unhook(self.hook)
            
    def keyboardEventReceived(self, event):
        if event.event_type == 'up':
            print(f"keyboardEventReceived: event_type -> {event.event_type}, event.name -> {event.name}")

            self.lineEdit_hotkey1.setText(f'{self.lineEdit_hotkey1.text()}{event.name}')
        
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):     
        key = event.key()
        print(f'key = {key} --- {event.text()}') 
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**:

> мне **`не обязательно использовать библиотеку keyboard`**.
>
> Ваше решение не позволяет заполнить qlineedit нажатой клавишей когда приложение в фокусе. (мне нужно заполнять строку только когда она в фокусе)
>
> Моей задачей стоит заполнение строки горячей клавишей для использования ей в дальнейшем как запуск другой функции (мне нужно сделать строку где я мог бы выбрать на какую клавишу забиндить функцию)
>
> ну например когда я нажимаю на **`ctrl`**, в строке не появляется `ctrl`

Обратите внимание:

- я убрал использование библиотеки **`keyboard`**;
- я заменил `QLineEdit` на `QLabel`.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.keymap = {}
        for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
            if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
                self.keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

        self.modmap = {
            Qt.ControlModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
            Qt.AltModifier:     self.keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
            Qt.ShiftModifier:   self.keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
            Qt.MetaModifier:    self.keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
            Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
            Qt.KeypadModifier:  self.keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
            }

        self.label = QLabel()                   
        
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in self.modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = self.keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.keyevent_to_string(event))
        self.label.setText(self.keyevent_to_string(event))

        if self.keyevent_to_string(event) == "Control+A":
            self.label.setText(f"{self.label.text()} \nCtrl+A <---- работает!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(300, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне не обязательно использовать библиотеку keyboard. Ваше решение не позволяет заполнить qlineedit нажатой клавишей когда приложение в фокусе. (мне нужно заполнять строку только когда она в фокусе) Моей задачей стоит заполнение строки горячей клавишей для использования ей в дальнейшем как запуск другой функции (мне нужно сделать строку где я мог бы выбрать на какую клавишу забиндить функцию)

Comment: ну например когда я нажимаю на ctrl, в строке не появляется ctrl

Comment: @MIkhail Вы пишите: 'Ваше решение не позволяет заполнить qlineedit нажатой клавишей когда приложение в фокусе.', как это понимать, если на первом изображении я показываю что это работает. А о том какая у вас задача и что вы хотите сделать, надо писать в теле вопроса, а не начинать что-то прояснять в комментариях.

Comment: я только учусь.

Comment: @MIkhail я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: это то что мне нужно, но как изменить странные названия клавиш. например у кнопки windows название meta

Comment: @MIkhail так как и `Control+A` изменяется в `Ctrl+A`. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour